# cannot convert from collection<Interface> to Microsoft.Practices.unity.injectionmember

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I use Dependency Injection et in the config file unity I include

```
container.RegisterType<ICollection<IModifObserver>>(new Collection<IModifObserver>() { new NotifyHisto() });
```

but I have error of conversion from cannot convert from `collection<IModifObserver>` to `Microsoft.Practices.unity.injectionmember`

I want fill my collection with an instance of object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to register an instance, use the `RegisterInstance` method like this:

```
container
    .RegisterInstance<ICollection<IModifObserver>>(
        new Collection<IModifObserver>() { new NotifyHisto() });
```

If you want the container to return a new instance every time you resolve, then you can use the `InjectionFactory` class with the `RegisterType` method like this:

```
container
    .RegisterType<ICollection<IModifObserver>>(
        new InjectionFactory(
            c => new Collection<IModifObserver>() { new NotifyHisto() }));
```